# Getting error while installing pysqlite

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pysqlite

I am trying to install pysqlite, but getting the below error-

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
copying lib\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
copying lib\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\dbapi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\factory.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\hooks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\regression.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\transactions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\userfunctions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
copying lib\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test\py25
copying lib\test\py25\py25tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test\py25
copying lib\test\py25\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test\py25
running build_ext
building 'pysqlite2._sqlite' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I have tried pip also.. but no luck !!

Can anyone please suggest the how to trace this error ? Thanks !

Comment: You are installing it on windows ?

Comment: yes, i am trying to install it on win8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838827/2116126

Answer (score 0):

You will ned to use a compiled binaries, you can download yours here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysqlite

Keep in mine that this is an Unofficial Windows Binaries, but it is works for me.